# How can I make a 2D map view using MapbBox in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, mapbox

I am looking to generate a 2D map with details like roads and buildings. Something like 3D but in 2D. Is there any way I can make this with Mapbox if I could do this with Mapbox Streets it would be awesome. Any ideas are welcome. I hope I posted in the right place, if not, please guide me to the right place.

Demo photo  : [image]

Comment: Start digging here: https://www.mapbox.com/unity/

Answer (score 1):

Map styles are processed as images in Unity so, in essence, they are all 2D. The 3D aspect comes in when you set up the vector layers in the `Map Features` part of the `AbstractMap.cs` script.

So, to use a 2D Mapbox map in Unity, you can use the [Mapbox Maps SDK for Unity](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/overview/) and follow the [use a custom style](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/overview/custom-maps/#use-a-custom-style) section of the documentation. After adding the style URL to the image source in Unity, you should have this 2D map all set up. To use the Mapbox Streets style directly, the style URL would be `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11`.